# Do multiple UPDATE using CTE

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use a CTE to do two update statements in Postgres and I'm not sure if there is a better approach to what I'm trying to do.

```
-- This script will update user records where the duplicate record value will overwrite the old value
WITH
update_users_Cte
AS
(
    SELECT 
        new.id new_user_id, 
        old.id old_user_id, 
        new.employee_id new_employee_id, 
        old.employee_id old_employee_id,
        new.display_name new_display_name, 
        old.display_name old_display_name,
        new.first_name new_first_name, 
        old.first_name old_first_name,
        new.last_name new_last_name , 
        old.last_name old_last_name,
        new.phone_number new_phone_number, 
        old.phone_number old_phone_number,
        new.job_type new_job_type, 
        old.job_type old_job_type,
        new.department_id new_department_id, 
        old.department_id old_department_id
    FROM users old
        JOIN users new ON (CONCAT(0, new.employee_id) = old.employee_id)
    WHERE LENGTH(new.employee_id) = 5 AND
        new.display_name != old.display_name OR
        new.first_name != old.first_name OR
        new.last_name != old.last_name OR
        new.phone_number != old.phone_number OR
        new.job_type != old.job_type OR
        new.department_id != old.department_id
)

UPDATE 
    users
SET 
    phone_number = NULL
FROM 
    update_users_Cte
WHERE 
    employee_id = update_users_Cte.new_employee_id

UPDATE 
    users
SET 
    display_name = update_users_Cte.new_display_name,
    first_name = update_users_Cte.new_first_name,
    last_name = update_users_Cte.new_last_name,
    phone_number = update_users_Cte.new_phone_number,
    job_type = update_users_Cte.new_job_type,
    department_id = update_users_Cte.new_department_id
FROM 
    update_users_Cte
WHERE 
    employee_id = update_users_Cte.old_employee_id
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
LINE 41: UPDATE
```

I would like to be able to do both UPDATEs and use the CTE as I need to check it in both cases. I'm not sure if I have to wrap the whole thing in a transaction.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
new_user_id | old_user_id | new_employee_id | old_employee_id | new_display_name | old_display_name | new_first_name | old_first_name | new_last_name | old_last_name | new_phone_number | old_phone_number |   new_updated_at    |   old_updated_at    | new_job_type | old_job_type  | new_department_id | old_department_id
-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------
         474 |       19710 | 35275           | 035275          |                  |                  | David          | David          | Coyle         | Coyle         | +447584208902    |                  | 2017-06-22 17:09:43 | 2021-01-27 15:14:43 |              |               |               418 |               418
       19701 |         432 | 21239           | 021239          |                  |                  | Piotr          | Piotr          | Mierniczek    | Mierniczek    |                  | +447404050330    | 2021-02-08 14:36:59 | 2017-06-22 17:09:42 |              |               |               249 |                73
       19702 |         479 | 35568           | 035568          |                  |                  | Manjita        | Manjita        | Kunwar        | Kunwar        |                  | +447847370860    | 2021-01-15 15:51:44 | 2021-01-15 15:45:20 |              |               |               317 |               317
       19707 |       19680 | 11111           | 011111          |                  | Sarika           | Sarika         | Sarika         | Sharma        | Sharma        |                  | +447700000000    | 2021-01-20 12:46:09 | 2021-01-20 12:45:12 |              | C.S. Employee |                   |
```

Comment: Sample data and/or the logic of the update would be helpful here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The only reason I'm doing the first UPDATE is because of a unique constraint on phone_number.

Comment: I ended up solving this by using a temp table. The CTE only lives in memory for a short while so it's unsuitable for multiple INSERT/UPDATE statements